# Increment all entries in an array by 'n' without a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, range

I have an array:

`arr = [5,5,5,5,5,5]`

I want to increment a particular range in the arr by 'n'. So if `n=2` and the range is `[2,5]`.
The array should look like this:

`arr = [5,5,7,7,7,5]`

Needed to do this *without a for loop*, for a problem im trying to solve.

**Tried:**

`arr[2:5] = [n]*3`

but that obviously replaces the entries and becomes:

`arr = [5,5,3,3,3,5]`

Any suggestions would be highly appriciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for standard python arrays or is a solution based on `numpy` also possible?

Comment: Does a list comprehension still count as a for loop? If not, `arr[range] = [n + x for x in arr[range]]` (where `range` is your range slice). Something similar to your approach would work with a `numpy`-array

Comment: Why no loop? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: does list comprehension count as a loop? that would be another way to solve it as well

Comment: Why are you not answering the clarification questions? Did you just dump this here and then walk away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 2
arr_range = slice(2, 5)                                                                                                                                                                           
arr = [5,5,7,7,7,5]                                                                                                                                                             
arr[arr_range] = map(lambda x: x+n, arr[arr_range])                                                                                                                                         
# arr                                                                                                                                                                             
# [5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 5]
```

But I would recommend using numpy...

```
import numpy as np
n = 2
arr_range = slice(2, 5)
arr = np.array([5,5,7,7,7,5])
arr[arr_range] += n
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually have a list, not an array. If you convert it to a Numpy array it is simple.

```
>>> n=3
>>> arr = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5])
>>> arr[2:5] += n
>>> arr
array([5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options (for code see below):

- Use slice assignment via a list comprehension (`a[:] = [x+1 for x in a]`),
- Use a for-loop (even though you exclude this in your question, I don't see a legitimate reason for doing so).

They come with pros and cons. Let's assume you are going to replace some fraction of the list items (as opposed to a fixed number of items). The for-loop runs in Python and hence might be slower but it has O(1) memory usage. The list comprehension and slice assignment both operate in C (assuming you are using CPython) but it has O(N) memory usage due to the temporary list.

Using a generator doesn't buy anything since it is converted to a list anyway before the assignment happens (this is necessary because if the generator had fewer or more items than the slice, the list would need to be resized accordingly; see [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ffd9753a944916ced659b2c77aebe66a6c9fbab5/Objects/listobject.c#L630)).

Using a `map` adds even more overhead since it needs to call the mapped function on every item.

The following is a performance comparison of the different methods. The for-loop is fastest for very small lists since it has minimal overhead (just the `range` object). For more than about a dozen items, the list comprehension clearly outperforms the other methods and especially for larger lists (`len(a) > 3e5`) the difference to the generator becomes noticeable (the generator cannot provide information about its size, so the generated list needs to be resized as more items are fetched). For very large lists the difference between for-loop and list comprehension seems to shrink again since the memory overhead tends to outweigh the loop cost, but reaching that point would require unusually large lists (where you'd be better off using something like Numpy anyway).

[image: Benchmarks]

This is the code using the [perfplot package](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/):

```
import numpy
import perfplot


def use_generator(a):
    i = slice(0, len(a)//2)
    a[i] = (x+1 for x in a[i])


def use_map(a):
    i = slice(0, len(a)//2)
    a[i] = map(lambda x: x+1, a[i])


def use_list(a):
    i = slice(0, len(a)//2)
    a[i] = [x+1 for x in a[i]]


def use_loop(a): 
    for i in range(len(a)//2): 
        a[i] += 1


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: [0]*n,
    kernels=[use_generator, use_map, use_list, use_loop],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(1, 26)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
    equality_check=None,
)
```